# Passing collection data to K2 custom service broker method

Tags: c#, xml, k2

I have two K2 SmartObjects: SmartObjectA gets a list of objects. SmartObjectB is a custom SmartObject that executes a custom create method with the list returned from SmartObjectA (basic smart object) as input parameter.

In the custom service broker's code behind, I need to deserialize the list value.

1. How can I pass the list received in K2 as an input parameter for the create method? I am using a multivalue property and assigning SmartObjectA properties to it.
2. What format does K2 use to serialize multivalues and how can I check what the input value format is so that I can map the list correctly?

SmartObject A Properties:

```
Name - SOType.Text,
ID - SOType.Number,
Date - SOType.Date,
Description - SOType.Text
```

SmartObject B - Property to be populated with SmartObjectA's list:

```
     [Property("LineItems", SoType.MultiValue, "LineItems", "The line items.")]
             public string LineItems
             {
                 get
                 {
                     return _lineItems;
                 }
                 set { _lineItems = value; }
             }
```

Input properties and Create method for SmartObjectB:

```
 [SourceCode.SmartObjects.Services.ServiceSDK.Attributes.Method("Create",
                 MethodType.Create,
                 "Create",
                 "Description",
                 new string[] { "CustomerId", "Date", "DueDate" },
                 new string[] { "CustomerId", "Date", "DueDate", "LineItems" },
                 new string[] { "TaxInvoiceId" })]
             public TaxInvoice Create()
             {
                 try
                 {
                    ..deserialize here
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Show us some code please

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have 2 different smartobjects, why not consider building a composite smartobject.

Using a composite smartobject, effectively **doesnt** require you to build a custom service broker.

[Composite Smartobject Creation](http://help.k2.com/kb001304#)

Comment: The custom service broker takes the received data from K2 and uses it to send REST requests to an external accounting system